# How to do an || statement inside a ternary?

Tags: php, ternary-operator

What I have right now is:

```
$somevar = ($progress_date != ('0000-00-00 00:00:00' || '//'))?$progress_date:'NA';
```

and it doesn't ever spit out $progress_date. It defaults to always printing 'NA' instead.

Doing this and using fewer () to separate things

```
$somevar = ($progress_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' || '//')?$progress_date:'NA';
```

makes it so $progress_date always spits out, even when the date is set to a string of 0's.

Is there a way using a ternary statement to catch both blank dates and dates set to 0 so that 'NA" gets printed out?

Comment: Use a proper if statement. Complex ternary statements are the road to madnesss!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like what you actually want is a pair of conditions with `&&`.

```
$somevar = ($progress_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' && $progress_date != '//')?$progress_date:'NA';
```

You need to have two sides to each boolean comparison, so you cannot do :

```
// Won't do what you expect
$somevar = $progress_date != ('thing1' || 'thing2') ? : ;
```

Instead make the full comparison on both sides.  Read out loud, it makes sense as what you need: *Progress date is not equal to thing1 and progress date is also not equal to thing2*

```
$somevar = $progress_date != "thing1" && $progress_date != "thing2" ? : ;
```

Comment: Thank you not only for an answer that works but also for explaining it to me. I understand now why it wasn't working before.

Answer (score 2):

```
$somevar = (!in_array($progress_date, array('0000-00-00 00:00:00','//')) ? $progress_date : 'NA';
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not using the or properly.

```
$somevar = ($progress_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' && $progress_date !='//') ? $progress_date:'NA';
```

Answer (score 0):

I think it should be

```
($progress_date != '0000-00-00 00:00:00' && $progress_date !='//')
```

`||` can't be used as you expected, because it always evaluates as boolean. That way `$progress_date != ('0000-00-00 00:00:00' || '//')` is effectively the same as:

```
$temp = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' || '//'; //gives true
$progress_date != $temp;
```